# sql COMPOSITE KEY help

Tags: mysql, sql, key

Using sql, i need to make Lineno and orderline into a composite key how can i do this this, so far i've got

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERLINE (
   ORDERNO INTEGER NOT NULL, 
   LINENO VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL, 
   NUMBERORDERED NUMERIC DEFAULT '1', 
   QUOTEDPRICE NUMERIC DEFAULT '0.00', 
   CONSTRAINT ORDERLINE_ORDERNO_PK PRIMARY KEY (ORDERNO), 
   CONSTRAINT ORDERLINE_ORDERNO_CC CHECK (ORDERNO BETWEEN 10000 AND 99999), 
   CONSTRAINT ORDERLINE_NUMBERORDERED CHECK (NUMBERORDERED BETWEEN 1 AND 100) 
);
```

Comment: Composite key?  As in "*primary* composite key"?  Or are you really after a unique constraint?  It's not clear to me...

Comment: As in _composite primary key_ - seems reasonable to me.  May cause some problems with brain-dead web infrastructure stuff that thinks you can only ever have single-column primary keys, but you really can have multi-column primary keys, and they are perfectly usable in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERLINE (
    ORDERNO INTEGER NOT NULL,
    LINENO VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    NUMBERORDERED NUMERIC DEFAULT '1',
    QUOTEDPRICE NUMERIC DEFAULT '0.00',
    CONSTRAINT ORDERLINE_ORDERNO_PK PRIMARY KEY(ORDERNO, LINENO), -- note alteration on this line
    CONSTRAINT ORDERLINE_ORDERNO_CC CHECK (ORDERNO BETWEEN 10000 AND 99999),
    CONSTRAINT ORDERLINE_NUMBERORDERED CHECK (NUMBERORDERED BETWEEN 1 AND 100)
);
```

You're very close.  Note the addition of the column name above.

Identify which field is more likely to be a leading column in any query and put it first.  For example; if you often access by OrderNO, LineNo that would be the best order, if however you access by LineNo, OrderNO go with that order.

Answer (score 2):

If you've already created the table, you can drop the existing primary key (presumably ORDERNO) and then re-create the primary key on two columns like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `orderline`  DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE `orderline`  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ORDERNO`, `LINENO`);
```

Alternately, you can define the primary key in your create table statement, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `orderline` (
    ORDERNO INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    LINENO VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL, 
    NUMBERORDERED NUMERIC DEFAULT '1', 
    QUOTEDPRICE NUMERIC DEFAULT '0.00',
    PRIMARY KEY (`ORDERNO`,`LINENO`),
    CONSTRAINT ORDERLINE_ORDERNO_CC CHECK (ORDERNO BETWEEN 10000 AND 99999), 
    CONSTRAINT ORDERLINE_NUMBERORDERED CHECK (NUMBERORDERED BETWEEN 1 AND 100) 
)
```